# Beautify WordPress HTML output without any plugins

Tags: html, code

Is there a simple (and without plugin) way to clean up the WordPress output of HTML? With a beautiful indentation of the code?
I don't understand why, but my HTML output isn't perfect and it makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: You might be able to use ob_start() and ob_get_clean() to capture all the output before it's written. Next, you would just need a mechanism to indent nested tags.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12243304

Answer (score 2):

Great question, I asked it myself and here's what I came up with. You can just use this in a custom plugin or in `functions.php`.

```php
// turn on Output Buffering (hence *ob*)
ob_start();
// register a callback to run after Wordpress has outputed everything
add_action('shutdown', function () { 
    // get the output buffer and store it to a variable
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    // setup the PHP native html beautifier called tidy
    // note that you need to have libtidy installed
    // but chances are that your server already have it
    $tidy = new \tidy;
    $tidy->parseString($html, [
        'indent' => true,
        'output-xhtml' => true,
        'wrap' => 200
    ], 'utf8');
    $tidy->cleanRepair();
    // output the beautified html
    echo $tidy;
    // Use 0 as third parameter to the add_action so you will
    // register the action as early as possible. Otherwise 
    //  Wordpress will flush the output buffer before you do...
}, 0);
```

Comment: additionally: enable Tidy with `extension=tidy.so` or `extension=php_tidy.dll` or `extension=tidy`

Do note that this may break a lots of stuff depending of your CSS.